# upload file using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, image

hitting a road block on this.

what I have so far:

```
  <input id="newFile" type="file"/>
  <span style="background-color:orange;" onClick="newImage()">HEYTRY</span>
```

This is obviously not very far.

I am looking for a basic way to load this image into a variable, convert the variable to something passable via a URL (ajax) and then accomplish my goal via php once it can extract the bits from the url.

not as easy as I anticipated.

any help would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work for every browser, but it's a nice way of doing multiple file uploads via AJAX:

```
function upload_files(entityKey, files, url, progress_callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), formData = new FormData();
  xhr.upload['onprogress'] = progress_callback;

  formData.append('entityKey', entityKey);
  $.each(files, function(i, file) { formData.append('file[]', file);});

  xhr.open("post", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

The entityKey is an example of a parameter on the server. The 'files' parameter comes from the 'files' attribute of the file-type input form element (as an array to support multiple). The 'progress_callback' parameter is a function that takes an object that has (at least) a 'loaded' and a 'total' field (unit is bytes). It doesn't care about the server response.

Answer (score 3):

I use this plugin for uploading files. http://www.uploadify.com/

Does that help at all?

Comment: thank you but i would really like to code it and understand what is going on

Comment: @jason why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I use this plug-in to upload a file.

[FORM PLUGIN](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins%3aForms)

u can use this plug-in method to pass your $_FILES data and use your PHP code later:

```
$('.yourFormUpload').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

for options variable u can read documentation of it